# R- Get a list of output value from a formula

Tags: r, formula, equation

I have a formula looks something like this: y=2+3x+x^2 and I have a list of inputs values that I would like to plug in x then graph it later.

So what I do is

```
x<-seq(-2,2, length.out=20)
formula <- y~2+3*x+x^2
```

But I'm not sure how to plug in a list of x values to the formula and get the output value from the codes. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could have defined a function to calculate the formula as below:

```
getScore <- function(x) {
  2+3*x+x^2
}
x <- seq(-2,2, length.out=20)
getScore(x)
 [1]  0.00000000 -0.16620499 -0.24376731 -0.23268698 -0.13296399  0.05540166
 [7]  0.33240997  0.69806094  1.15235457  1.69529086  2.32686981  3.04709141
[13]  3.85595568  4.75346260  5.73961219  6.81440443  7.97783934  9.22991690
[19] 10.57063712 12.00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your formula into a function and use `sapply`:

```
x = seq(-2,2, length.out=20)

my.function = function(x){
  return(2+3*x+x^2)
}

y = sapply(x, my.function)
> y
 [1]  0.00000000 -0.16620499 -0.24376731 -0.23268698 -0.13296399  0.05540166  0.33240997
 [8]  0.69806094  1.15235457  1.69529086  2.32686981  3.04709141  3.85595568  4.75346260
[15]  5.73961219  6.81440443  7.97783934  9.22991690 10.57063712 12.00000000
```

If you would like a `list`, then use `lapply` instead of `sapply`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong here, but there's also no need to `sapply` because all calculations in `my.function` are vectorized.  Calling `my.function(x)` will return the same result as calling `sapply(x, my.function)`. See, e.g., the answer by @Sonny.  A quick speed test suggests that directly calling the function is 22x faster that using `sapply` (although this doesn't matter if `x` is of any reasonable size, since the difference will be nanoseconds)

Answer (score 0):

`fn$` in gsubfn can be used to convert a formula to a function.  If a function such as `identity` is prefaced with `fn$` then a formula in the arguments will be converted to a function and then the function that `fn$` prefaces will be run. The LHS of the formula should be the input variable to the function or empty.  In the latter case it will use the free variables on the RHS as the arguments.  The RHS is the body.

```
library(gsubfn)

fo[[2]] <- NULL   # remove LHS
fun <- fn$identity(fo)   # create function from formula

fun
## function (x) 
## 2 + 3 * x + x^2

fun(x)
##  [1]  0.00000000 -0.16620499 -0.24376731 -0.23268698 -0.13296399  0.05540166
##  [7]  0.33240997  0.69806094  1.15235457  1.69529086  2.32686981  3.04709141
## [13]  3.85595568  4.75346260  5.73961219  6.81440443  7.97783934  9.22991690
## [19] 10.57063712 12.00000000
```